# what does it mean for $a$ to be in the set $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I'm learning about p adic interpolation now and have been the encountering the set  $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$ lately.
What is this set and what does it contain?

Thank you!

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001471)

Answer (score 1):

$$1+p\Bbb Z_p=\{1+pa:a\in\Bbb Z_p\}$$
is the set of elements of $\Bbb Z_p$ with the property that $x\equiv1\pmod p$.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z_p$ is the set of $p$-adic integers. $p\Bbb Z_p$ is the set of all the multiples of $p$. Add $1$ to all of those, and you get $1+p\Bbb Z_p$.

This is standard notation in algebra and related fields. If $X$ is a set of elements in some algebraic structure, $x$ is an element of some (not necessarily the same) algebraic structure, and $*$ is a binary operation which can be applied to $x$ and the elements of $X$, then
$$
x*X=\{x*y\mid y\in X\}
$$
Similarly we can define $X*x$, and $X*Y$ for a set $Y$.